# URL rewriting with OcpSoft rewrite Join.path rule

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, prettyfaces, ocpsoft-rewrite

I'm using Ocpsoft Rewrite, to perform URL rewriting in a JSF project. I have a redirect rule, which works fine:

```
.addRule()
        .when(Direction.isInbound().and(Path.matches("/venue/{id}")))
        .perform(Redirect.temporary(context.getContextPath() + 
                "/protected/index.xhtml?venueID={id}"));
```

However, because of the redirect, this changes the URL in the navigation bar. I thought I could use a Join rule instead, but it doesn't work as i expected:

```
.addRule(Join.path("/venue/{venueID}").to("/protected/index.xhtml"))
        .perform(Log.message(Level.INFO, "Rewrite is active!"));
```

I thought this rule would redirect from, for example, `foo/venue/123` to `foo/protected/index.xhtml?venueID=123`, but I don't get the `?venueID=...` parameter appended to the URL.

Anyone knows what the correct rule should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule looks correct. But a Join doesn't result in a redirect. Instead it forwards the request internally. This means that the URL isn't changed. So you won't "see" the parameter `venueID` in the URL. But you will be able to read the parameter using the standard Servlet API:

```
String id = HttpServletRequest.getParameter("venueID");
```

Comment: I have the same problem in a GWT application, but I can't get the parameter on GWT side with: Window.Location.getParameter("param");

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, you can do a `Forward` instead:

```
.addRule()
.when(Direction.isInbound().and(Path.matches("/venue/{id}")))
.perform(Forward.to("/protected/index.xhtml?venueID={id}"));
```

But this won't handle outbound HTML link correction like Join will!

Comment: OK, but if there are other parameters, those would be forwarded or not?

Comment: No, it will only forward the parameters you specify in the pattern.

Comment: However, as Christian mentioned earlier. All parameters, including original ones from the original URL, will be available via the standard Servlet API:

Comment: String id = HttpServletRequest.getParameter("venueID");

Comment: How to reach those parameters on GWT side? Window.Location.getParameter("param") does not work.

Comment: You will need to provide the parameters via a web-service. Server-side parameters are not available on the client side unless you expose them directly.

Comment: You can also parse the values out of the URL directly on the client side if you need them.

Comment: But in that case on change I have to also rewrite manually on the client side skipping the ocl library rigth? To be concrete, I want to pretty this app http://log4jtester.com/ to replace "?p=" with "/pattern/" for example. (It rewrites url instantly as pattern changes)

Comment: Not at all. You just need to parse the new URL of whatever the page URL is, and pull out the information you need on the client side: `window.getLocation()` etc... It's completely independent of the server side.